# Changing button label in the container view by clicking button in the main view

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, containers, segue

I'm new to IOS programming. In my app, I have a container view which is connected to a page view controller with three pages. It works well. When I push a button in the main view controller, I want to change the button labels in the container view. So, I must connect a variable in the main view to a variable in the page view controller. I write like the below, but it crashes when I clicked the button (SIGABRT signal)..

```
@IBAction func pressShift(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (self.shift != 3) {
        self.shift++
    }
    else {
        self.shift = 1
    }
    performSegueWithIdentifier("container", sender: sender)
}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    var scene = segue.destinationViewController as! FeaturesViewController
    scene.shiftNumber = self.shift
}
```

I made a simple example project. A container view in the main view. There is a label in the container view (not page view controller) and a button in the main view. I wrote the same code, but again the same error occurs.
Here is the image of my storyboard...

[Storyboard Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTmUS.png)

Example project: http://www.filedropper.com/exampletosegue

Comment: A few things, you should check the segueIdentifier in prepareForSeque if(segue.identifier == "container"){...} and I think you should write "as?" instead of "as!" (I am not sure if that is what is causing your crash. I'm also new to swift)

Comment: segueIdentifier is correct. When I debug, prepareForSegue method is called when I push the button. After the implementation of the method, it crashes. Also, checked the "as?". Not worked..

Comment: maybe check if self.shift != nil

Comment: No, I've already initialized it as 1..

Comment: maybe destinationViewController is not of type FeaturesViewController.

Comment: But, segue is working when it loads..? The problem is when the button is clicked..

Comment: Your action method is in which class? And your page view controller is FeaturesViewController?

Comment: viewController class.. Yes, the page view controller is FeaturesViewController..

Comment: performSegueWithIdentifier("container", sender: sender)
Here change the sender to self.

Comment: From this above code only changing to self, it should work, if not the problem may be in storyboard segue from the button. So check once how segue is designed there in storyboard, wether from button or not.

Comment: No, not fixed. Changing to self does not fix the problem. I couldn't find any problem in the storyboard. I wrote a simple project. A container view in the main view controller. I put a simple label in the container view's view controller (not page view controller) and a button at the main view controller. I wrote the same code above. But again it doesn't work. I think I made the same and yet unknown mistake..

Comment: Here is the error in the output: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'There are unexpected subviews in the container view. Perhaps the embed segue has already fired once or a subview was added programmatically?

Comment: Could you post the example project?

Comment: Sure. http://www.filedropper.com/exampletosegue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing the child view which has already created at the first start..

```
@IBAction func insertButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    if (shiftNo != 3) {
        shiftNo++
    }
    else {
        shiftNo = 1
    }

    var childView = self.childViewControllers[0] as! UIViewController
    childView.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
    childView.view.removeFromSuperview()
    childView.removeFromParentViewController()

    performSegueWithIdentifier("container", sender: self)
}
```